# How to avoid MemoryError when using fetch_openml()?

Tags: mnist

I am using the following code to get mnist

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1, cache=True)
```

It has worked before but now i get this error:

[image: MemoryError]

Does anyone know a solution to this? Much appreciated, thanks